# Cannot find user site directory for Python site packages

Tags: python, sitedirectory

I am looking to add a custom module to my user site directory. After looking at SO, I found the command:

```
python -m site --user-site
```

that will return the user site directory. However, I cannot find the file location:

```
(base) C:\Users\inval>python -m site --user-site
C:\Users\inval\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages
```

In the Roaming folder, there is no Python folder and I have unhid all the files. Can anyone advise? I have also copied the directory and pasted it directly into file explorer but to no avail.

Comment: May depend on where you installed Python, isn’t there a choice during installation? - I install to c:\Python39 and packages I install go into c:\Python39\lib\site-pacakges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 commands you can use to get the path to site packages:

The following will show you the path to the globally installed site packages

```
python -m site
```

and this command will show you the packages installed for that particular user

```
python -m site --user-site
```

In your case it might be that the packages are all installed globally and not for a user.

Comment: Hi thank you for all your replies. May I ask what you mean by installed globally and not for a user? My apologies I am new.

Comment: Hey @Tim , installing a package locally means installing it for a particular user's use. While, when you install the package globally it is installed for all users on that computer and everyone can use them. 
In your case, it seems that you are on a windows machine, and on windows, by default the packages are installed globally, that is why the command "python -m site" will be more helpful to you.

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation. Truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

That's where Python expects the directory to be, *if it exists*. If it does not exist, you can simply create it.